# Is there a way to select top values from a database where each value has a unique foreign key for a leaderboard system?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Sorry if the title is a bit confusing but I'm trying to query a database so that it returns the top 5 'score' values but each value has to have a unique foreign key 'player_ID' for a leaderboard system so the same player can't be in the top 5 twice.

Here is the database with a few of the entries:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dysgc.png

Answer (score 1):

I think the title is a bit misleading. After reading the description, I believe what you want is not to filter out records with non-unique `player_ID` values, but simply to skip the records with a `player_ID` that was already counted as a "top" record. If so, here is a solution...

Since you've tagged `python`, I assume you're not looking for an SQL-only solution. One simple way to do this is to first query the "top" records like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY score DESC
```

and then in your code loop over the records and simply ignore the "duplicate" ones.

Here is an example:

```
player_ids_so_far = set()
top_records = []
for r in records:
    player_id = r['player_ID']
    if player_id in player_ids_so_far:
        continue  # Simply skip this record
    player_ids_so_far.add(player_id)
    top_records.append(r)
    if len(top_records) == 5:
        break
```